# Media queries are requiring !important to work even though its at the bottom of my css and I have no inline css

Tags: css, css-selectors, media-queries

I have seen a lot of questions on here where people are needing to use `!important` but they have inline CSS that isn't getting overwritten. I do not have any inline CSS. I am using SCSS with individual SCSS files.

I actually noticed this in my last project I did too. I needed to use `!important` in the media queries, but I was trying out TailwindCSS so I thought it had something to do with that. In the Tailwind project, I didn't use SCSS.

As far as I can tell, everything is in the right order. I am technically only using one CSS file, so there shouldn't be an issue with the order there. The ONLY thing I can think of is an issue with either Font Awesome or jQuery, but I don't think that's the issue. I am honestly at a loss for what this issue could be. I feel like I am doing something dumb.

The only other thing I can think of is it might be something wrong with Visual Studio Code's extension for live server? Things have been buggy for me with that lately. When I launched live server, it would open the local host tab at 150% zoom. And today, if I used the dev tools, it would randomly make text like 200px tall. I needed to close dev tools and reopen them to get it to look right.

Below is snippets of the code, but if that is not enough, I have this project updated as a GitHub repo here: [https://github.com/rperry99/theEssen/](https://github.com/rperry99/theEssen/tree/navigation)

Here is what is in my main SCSS file where I am importing all the other files:

```css
@import "helpers.scss";
@import "normalize.scss";
@import "nav.scss";

@import "mediaQueries.scss";
```

I checked the output CSS file, and the media queries are at the bottom like they should be:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,700;1,400&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Montserrat", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

body {
  overflow-x: hidden; }

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative; }
  nav #logo {
    color: #dd6031;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: bold; }
  nav #hamburger {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column; }
    nav #hamburger .bar {
      width: 100%;
      background: #dd6031;
      height: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px; }
    nav #hamburger:hover {
      cursor: pointer; }
  nav #navContent {
    background: #f1f6ef;
    padding: 1rem;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 50vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease; }
    nav #navContent a {
      color: #dd6031;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 1.5rem; }
      nav #navContent a:hover {
        color: #eba489;
        cursor: pointer; }
    nav #navContent .close {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      margin: 1rem;
      font-size: 2rem;
      font-weight: bold; }
    nav #navContent .socials {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
      align-items: center;
      width: 75%; }

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  right: -9999px;
  top: -9999px; }

.show {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1; }

@media (min-width: 767px) {
  nav {
    align-items: flex-end; }
  #navContent {
    right: 0 !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    flex-direction: row !important;
    justify-content: flex-end !important;
    background: none !important;
    width: max-content !important; }
    #navContent a {
      margin-right: 20px; }
  #hamburger,
  .close {
    display: none !important; }
  .socials {
    width: max-content !important; } }
```

I have tested each individual property without !important and each one that has it here NEEDS it or it won't work. Here is my media query partial:

```css
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  nav {
    align-items: flex-end;
  }
  #navContent {
    right: 0 !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    flex-direction: row !important;
    justify-content: flex-end !important;
    background: none !important;
    width: max-content !important;
    a {
      margin-right: 20px;
    }
  }
  #hamburger,
  .close {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .socials {
    width: max-content !important;
  }
}
```

Here is my HTML for reference:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>The Essen</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <a href="#" id="logo">The Essen</a>
      <div id="hamburger">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="navContent" class="hide">
        <a class="close">X</a>
        <a href="#">about</a>
        <a href="#">recipies</a>
        <a href="#">gallery</a>
        <div class="socials">
          <a href="#" class="social fa fa-facebook"></a>
          <a href="#" class="social fa fa-instagram"></a>
          <a href="#" class="social fa fa-twitter"></a>
          <a href="#" class="social fa fa-pinterest"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a matter of *specifity*. Just use `nav #navContent` as a selector in your media query instead of just `#navContent` and you won't need the `!important`. Similar for the other rules: In media queries, always use a selector at least as specific as the corresponding selector in the general rules.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, that was the issue. What's weird to me though, is I didn't seem to have this issue before. I usually just target the specific element like how I did in the above CSS and I never ran into an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Bro, you kidding? Just placing a CSS below other CSS doesn't provide it the right to overrride. `This is only valid scenario if the conflict involves same classes, same ids, same elements, etc.` In 99% cases the `combination used at different places` is different.

**CSS Specificity**

> Specificity is a weight that is applied to a given CSS declaration, determined by the number of each selector type in the matching selector. When multiple declarations have equal specificity, the last declaration found in the CSS is applied to the element. Specificity only applies when the same element is targeted by multiple declarations. As per CSS rules, directly targeted elements will always take precedence over rules which an element inherits from its ancestor.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#:~:text=Specificity%20is%20a%20weight%20that,type%20in%20the%20matching%20selector.&text=As%20per%20CSS%20rules%2C%20directly,element%20inherits%20from%20its%20ancestor.

Comment: Unless I learned something wrong, I thought that the bottom most styles in a CSS file is what gets applied. So if I set the background to blue on line one, then set the background to green on line 50, it will take green as the background color, assuming both are the same specificity. I mean, I am still relatively new to this.